# Cannot read propertyof undefined when importing local JSON file - Angular/Ionic

Tags: json, angular, typescript, ionic4

I want to display data in an html file coming from a local json file.

My JSON looks like:

```
{
"ACCESSIBILITY_EXPANDED": "Expanded",
      "ACCESSIBILITY_BACK": "Back",
      "ACCESSIBILITY_COLLAPSED": "Collapsed",
      "ACCESSIBILITY_PHONE_NUMBER": "Call us at",
      "ACCESSIBILITY_EMAIL": "Email us at",
      "ACCESSIBILITY_ADDRESS": "Visit us at",
      "ACCESSIBILITY_FAX": "Send us a FAX at",
}
```

What i did so far is change my tsconfig.json to look like this:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
      "src/typings.d.ts"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
  }
}
```

Added a file called in src folder called typings.d.ts which looks like this:

```
declare module "*.json" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}
```

And then in my component's .ts file i did.

`import en from '../../assets/i18n/en.json';`

However in my html file when i did something like

```
 <span class="bolded"> {{ en.ACCESSIBILITY_BACK }}</span>
```

i got an error saying  Cannot read property ACCESSIBILITY_BACK of undefined. When I console.log(en) in ngOnInit() it's logs my object fine.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`{{ en }}` is a template property, so you need to assign it to a component property:

```
@Component({
  template: '...<span class="bolded"> {{ en.ACCESSIBILITY_BACK }}</span>...'
})
export class A11yComponent {
  // assigns `en` from json to a component property `en`
  en = en;
}
```

You could also use interpolation in the template string / concatenation, but this will not be allowed with AoT compilation.

Comment: hey, after adding that en = en line of code i got an error "Can't resolve '../../assets/i18n/en.json"

Comment: That’s a separate issue related to how your imports / files are structured.